# C++ 2D vector clear works as intended?

Tags: c++, vector

I want to make sure that the following works as I intend without memory leaks:

```
vector<vector <float> > X;
for (int i = 0; i < some_size; i++)
{
     vector<float> column;
     X.push_back(column);
}
// ... use 2D array somehow
X.clear(); 
/* CALLS DESTRUCTOR OF EACH ELEMENT, BUT SINCE EACH ELEMENT
IS A VECTOR, CLEAR IS RECURSIVELY CALLED ON EACH OF THOSE*/
```

That is, is `clear()` recursively applied to vectors of vectors due to `clear` being part of a vector's destructor?

I know `X` is cleared fully when it goes out of scope but that is not the point of the question here.

Comment: Yes. (insert more characters)

Comment: FYI, your `for` loop could be simplified to `X.resize(some_size)` or you could just create it as `vector<vector <float> > X(some_size);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.  It will call the destructor for each element in the top vector, and the destructor for each vector will clear it's own memory (so it isn't calling `clear` necessarily for each of the inner vectors).

`clear` is *not* guaranteed to free up the memory used by the top level vector, however.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What do you mean by top, X? So what should I do after clear() if I need to do this before X goes out of scope?

Comment: @Tommy:  "top" in this context is meaning the outer vector (the first dimension of the 2D vector you are creating here).  As each element in that vector is also a vector.  When you call `clear`, it will call the destructor for every element (each of the vectors) within it.  It is not guaranteed to free up the space *it* (meaning the outer vector) is using.  If you want to do that as well, you can do that by `vector<vector<float>>().swap(X)`, which will effectively reduce the capacity of the vector to the implementation's default capacity.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Zac Howland's answer, as the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/clear/) for `vector<T>::clear` suggests,

> A reallocation is not guaranteed to happen, and the vector capacity is
>   not guaranteed to change due to calling this function. A typical
>   alternative that forces a reallocation is to use swap:

```
vector<T>().swap(x);   // clear x reallocating
```

This will swap the contents of a temporary empty vector with those of `x`.  Then the destructor will be called for the temporary (previously empty) vector, which will in turn call the destructors for all of its vector elements, and finally all space will be deallocated.

Comment: swap will not reallocate

Comment: @DieterLücking: I didn't say it will (actually I didn't even use that word, the excerpt is from the documentation).  In the last paragraph, I'm explaining why the space will be **de**allocated; it's not the `swap` that does it, it's the temporary empty vector.